# C# TCP Listener stops after error

Tags: c#, tcp, tcplistener

I have a windows service which listens to a tcp port and does some operations (com port) when it get any packets. I am using come from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx url.

The code works fine but the process/WhileLoop gets stopped if any error occurs inside the second while loop (the error is handled inside the second while loop separately in try catch blocks).

I want the service to keep listening/processing next packets even after previous one's processing caused error.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread _thread = new Thread(DoTask);
            _thread.Name = Utility.THREAD_NAME;
            _thread.IsBackground = true;
            _thread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.WriteLog("Error Occurred in Service Start: OnStart():" + ex.Message);
        }

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // TODO: Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
    }

    protected void DoTask()
    {
        TcpListener server=null;   
        try
        {
            // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
            Int32 port = 8002;
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Any;

            // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            // Start listening for client requests.
            server.Start();

            // Buffer for reading data
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            String data = null;

            // Enter the listening loop. 
            while(true) 
            {
                Utility.WriteLog("Waiting for a connection... ");

                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Utility.WriteLog("Connected!");

                data = null;

                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();

                int i;

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client. 
                while((i = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0) 
                {

                    //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);                        
                    Utility.WriteLog("Received: " + data);

                    string CartCommand = data;

                    #region PROCESSING AT COMMAND AT FIRMWARE

                    try
                    {
                        string SerialResponse = string.Empty;
                        CreateSerialPort();
                        if (_serialPort.IsOpen == false)
                        {
                            _serialPort.Open();
                        }

                        _serialPort.Write(CartCommand); /* Execute Network Supplied Command to Serial Port */
                        Thread.Sleep(_ResponseWait);

                        byte[] SPResponsebyte = new byte[_serialPort.ReadBufferSize];
                        int intSPtBytes = _serialPort.Read(SPResponsebyte, 0, SPResponsebyte.Length); /* Read the Serial Port Response after Command Execution */
                        SerialResponse = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(SPResponsebyte, 0, intSPtBytes);

                        SPResponsebyte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SerialResponse);
                        networkStream.Write(SPResponsebyte, 0, SPResponsebyte.Length);

                        Utility.WriteLog(SerialResponse);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Utility.WriteLog("Error: " + ex.Message);
                        // This is the problem area, the while loop don't accept next commands after this.
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (_serialPort.IsOpen == true)
                        {
                            _serialPort.Close();
                        }
                    }

                    #endregion

                    // Send back a response.
                    //stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                    //Utility.WriteLog("Sent: " + data);
                }

                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(SocketException e)
        {                
            Utility.WriteLog("SocketException: " + e);
        }            
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening for new clients.
            server.Stop();
            Utility.WriteLog("Stop listening.");
        }

        Utility.WriteLog("Cycle complete.");

      }

    private bool CreateSerialPort()
    {
        try
        {

            _configDoc = new ConfigDoc();

            if (_configDoc != null)
            {
                _serialPort = new SerialPort();
                _serialPort.PortName = _configDoc.PortName;
                _serialPort.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(_configDoc.BaudRate);
                _serialPort.Parity = _configDoc.ParityBit;
                _serialPort.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(_configDoc.DataBits);
                _serialPort.StopBits = _configDoc.StopBits;
                //_localIPAddress = _configDoc.LocalIPAddress;
                _TCPPort = Convert.ToInt32(_configDoc.TCPPort);
                _ResponseWait = Convert.ToInt32(_configDoc.ResponseWait);
                _SerialTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(_configDoc.SerialTimeout);

                _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                //SORABH - Do we need this wired event?
                //_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPort_DataReceived);
                _serialPort.ReadTimeout = _SerialTimeout;
                _serialPort.WriteTimeout = _SerialTimeout;
                _serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
                _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
                _serialPort.Open();

                //if (keepPortOpen == false)
                //{
                //    _serialPort.Close();
                //}

                //_backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
                //_backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                //_backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                //_backgroundWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorker_DoWork;
                //_backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync("Background Worker");   

                _FlagServiceStarted = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Utility.WriteLog("Serial Port Information not Initialized in Utility -> ");
                return false;
            }                

            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.WriteLog("Unable to open the given Serial Port: CreateSerialPort():-> " + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You never get next packet, because you close client connection with client.Close();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by **writing data back to Network stream in catch block**. Now second while loop like below

```
// Loop to receive all the data sent by the client. 
                    while ((i = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {

                        //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

                        // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                        Utility.WriteLog("Received: " + data);

                        string CartCommand = data;

                        #region PROCESSING AT COMMAND AT FIRMWARE

                        try
                        {
                            string SerialResponse = string.Empty;
                            CreateSerialPort();
                            if (_serialPort.IsOpen == false)
                            {
                                _serialPort.Open();
                            }

                            _serialPort.Write(CartCommand); /* Execute Network Supplied Command to Serial Port */
                            Thread.Sleep(_ResponseWait);

                            byte[] SPResponsebyte = new byte[_serialPort.ReadBufferSize];
                            int intSPtBytes = _serialPort.Read(SPResponsebyte, 0, SPResponsebyte.Length); /* Read the Serial Port Response after Command Execution */
                            SerialResponse = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(SPResponsebyte, 0, intSPtBytes);

                            SPResponsebyte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SerialResponse);
                            networkStream.Write(SPResponsebyte, 0, SPResponsebyte.Length);

                            Utility.WriteLog(SerialResponse);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Utility.WriteLog("Error: " + ex.Message);

                            byte[] SPResponsebyte = new byte[_serialPort.ReadBufferSize];
                            SPResponsebyte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("COMERROR"); // explicitly initializing with blank response
                            networkStream.Write(SPResponsebyte, 0, SPResponsebyte.Length); // force output to network stream

                            Utility.WriteLog("Blank response sent back to network stream");

                            // This is the problem area, the while loop don't accept next commands after this.
                        }

                        #endregion

                    }
```

Thanks a lot to Keith for his valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Would like to see your exception to answer more concisely, however:

```
while((i = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0)
```

This is not inside your inner try/catch, and so any error reading from the socket will kill your thread/process. Look at the code that's not inside your try/catch as the likely problem.

Comment: Thanks keith. I put exception blocks in there but no luck. 
if you notice the code, I am capturing the network packet and then sends those to a SERIAL port, now if anything goes wrong at the serial port level >> it catches the error and then it never listens to new incoming requests. The error gets caught below Utility.WriteLog(SerialResponse); line.

Comment: Example, a successful capture:
>>Waiting for a connection... >> Connected! >> Received: 1C9 >> 11022070043900040A9 >> TCP Connection closed.........................
       
Example, an unsuccessful capture: >> Waiting for a connection... >> >> Connected! >> Received: 9C1 >> Error: The operation has timed out.

Comment: If you get an error at the SerialPort level, you don't close the TCP connection and start listening again, you just continue reading from the existing connection it looks like.

Comment: Keith, please advice what coding changes I need to do for this.

Comment: I'm not going to write your code for you, I can tell you what the problem(s) are and why you're having them. A good start would be moving the inner try/catch out around the while loop, so any exception, serial or network, will start over. There are other problems with your code, for example you are not handling TCP socket data very well. There is not a guarantee that each networkStream.Read will return one and only one complete command. TCP packets can get fragmented, and the network stream can presumably buffer extra data. Your protocol would need some kind of command delimiter for example.

Comment: Hey Keith. I solved the issue, thanks to your suggestion there. The issue was that when software encounter errors it goes in CATCH block, which was NOT WRITING anything back to the network stream, this was causing the stream to expect data in endless mode. I wrote dummy data to network stream in catch block and now it works. Thanks again.